# Why my page not work when i add www.irctc.co.in in my url then page redirect on that site while its working good

Tags: php, curl

I want irctc.co.in page load in my page.Why my page not work when i add www.irctc.co.in in my url then page redirect on that site while its working good. So please tell me the thing that it do not redirect on that site that site load in my webpage.

```
<?php
// URLs we want to retrieve
$urls = array(
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.bing.com',
'http://www.yahoo.com',
'http://www.twitter.com',
'http://www.facebook.com',


'www.irctc.co.in'         //it creates problem WHY

);

// initialize the multihandler
$mh = curl_multi_init();

$channels = array();
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
// initiate individual channel
$channels[$key] = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($channels[$key], array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));

// add channel to multihandler
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $channels[$key]);
}

// execute - if there is an active connection then keep looping
$active = null;
do {
$status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
}
while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);

// echo the content, remove the handlers, then close them
foreach ($channels as $chan) {
echo curl_multi_getcontent($chan);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chan);
curl_close($chan);
}

// close the multihandler
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `https://` before the `www.irctc.co.in` , Also you need to enable this cURL parameter.

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERIFYPEER => false
```